# Fix Navbar to top while scrolling down so far

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive been trying for hours to figure out how I may have a my navigational bar float to the top after you scroll past my logo.  No code I've tried has worked.. can anyone help me?  I only need it to work when it the site is viewed in mobile.  You can view my code and preview it below

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFDXBMXH3Q1Z

Comment: Add your code here, not the link to it. And only add the portions that constitute the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove overflow:hidden from your body and add this class

```
#myTopnav.active
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

and some javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var shrinkHeader = 50;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
              var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
                if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
                     $('#myTopnav').addClass('active');

                  }
                  else {
                      $('#myTopnav').removeClass('active');
                  }
            });
            function getCurrentScroll() {
            return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            }

        });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for the code..  does what I want it to do.. but the problem is when you click my dropdown menu once you scrolled down.. the dropdown menu won't appear... in face the whole menu disappears itself??   CSS Glitch Maybe?

Comment: But am getting no issue in your code..dropdown is working fine as well

Comment: Really??  Lol. Idk maybe it's just my PC being dorky...  I'll try again..

Comment: I tried it again.. but this time on my phone... when u scroll down the page the bar is still there but when ur scrolled down and click the menu to drop down, the whole bar disappears...  Maybe I input something wrong..  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFFC15UR432Q

Comment: Works just added a little code to the script as you can see thank you so much for the help https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFFGWSKM6TDZ

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Following code in different events . I have checked in mouseWheel . Add this code in your Script.

```
window.onmousewheel = function(){
    var myDiv = $("div.fixed");
    var logoHead = $(".t1 tbody tr:first-child");
    console.log('logoHead = = ',logoHead.offset().top);
    if(logoHead.offset().top<-33){
        myDiv.css("position","fixed");
    }
    else{
        myDiv.css("position","relative");
    }
}
```

Comment: works great sir thank you..  one problem i'm having though is I only want it to work when the menu is in  mobile view..  i'm playing with your script right now to see what I may be able to do